# product of Meijer-G function and exponential

Tags: special-functions

I have a product of the form $e^{-tx}\times G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(x\left|\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf{a}_n, \mathbf{a}_{p-n}\\
\mathbf{b}_m, \mathbf{b}_{q-m}\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)$. I need to write the product as Meijer's-G function. I know the shifting property $z^{\mu}G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(x\left|\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf{a}_n, \mathbf{a}_{p-n}\\
\mathbf{b}_m, \mathbf{b}_{q-m}\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right) = G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(x\left|\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf{a}_n+\mu, \mathbf{a}_{p-n}+\mu\\
\mathbf{b}_m+\mu, \mathbf{b}_{q-m}+\mu\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)$ form [NIST](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234783338_NIST_Handbook_of_Mathematical_Functions). Is there a similar property for this?

Also where can I find an academic reference (book/paper) about this subject (product of two Meijer G functions) or at least its special cases if any exists? I know this formulae exists [Wolfram-MeijerG-product](https://functions.wolfram.com/07.34.16.0003.01) but I don't know how to use it for this case unfortunately!

Any help and hint is appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The formula you linked from Wolfram functions is for the two variable Meijer G function, defined by a double integral. Also, maybe the limit definition of $e^x$ can be used

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Can you please elaborate more on how to do that? Should I write $e^x$ as series?